# Advanced search navigation to inside the website

Tags: html, security

The website we are making has an advanced search option in the home page and when we click it goes inside the website .Is this a good practice? I have not seen this type of navigation in any top websites. They don't have this option. You don't have to register for advanced search in our website. our website asks users to input a lot of data. Is this good practice? can an attacker get into the website when advanced search goes inside the website?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking:

- is it the mere fact to have search? There is code behind which is supposed to make a query into something (usually a database).
- that there is no authentication? I do not know if it is needed. Is there information which should be available to only some kind of people when doing a search? In such a case authentication is needed somewhere.
- that a search function can be a security risk? Yes it can. All depends on how it is coded and it is possible to have vulnerabilities which use the search code to access data outside the expected perimeter. [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org) covers such questions.

Comment: we are trying to add a advanced search which any anonymous person can do. This I haven't seen in any other website. Will this be an advantage or disadvantage to the website?